react-router-dom match path that ends with specific suffix
I'm trying to upgrade my app from react-router-dom v4 to v6 and I just encounter an issue, I had a path like this. <Route path="*/AlertWeb" render={() => <YourComponent />} /> which basically match everything if it ends with /AlertWeb, so basically it can be localhost:3000/AlertWeb or localhost:3000/login/AlertWeb I realise this is not working on v6 I'm wondering if anyone might know if is it possible to do this in v6 and how to do it
I try to do the same but it is not working and according to chatGPT this should work but it is not
<Route path="/(.*)/your-pattern" element={<YourComponent />} />

React-Router-DOM 6 doesn't match routes like this at all. You'll have to explicitly declare each route at each level of nesting to reproduce this behavior.
Example:
<Routes>
  <Route path="somePath">
    ...
    <Route path="someOtherPath">
      ...
      <Route path="anotherPath">
        ...

        {/* "/somePath/someOtherPath/anotherPath/alertweb" */}
        <Route path="alertweb" element={<AlertWeb />} />
      </Route>
      ...

      {/* "/somePath/someOtherPath/alertweb" */}
      <Route path="alertweb" element={<AlertWeb />} />
    </Route>
    ...

    {/* "/somePath/alertweb" */}
    <Route path="alertweb" element={<AlertWeb />} />
  </Route>
  ...

  {/* "/alertweb" */}
  <Route path="alertweb" element={<AlertWeb />} />
</Routes>

